# Find and replce string

Tags: string

I have one string as string1= this is my name.

In string 1 find "is" i.e. Find string= "is"

replace string= "was"
final op=this was my name. Explain with c language.

Comment: man sed? vi? notepad? What language? And so on..

Comment: I didn't understand anything... Google Translator fail?

Comment: hmm, interesting question. Let me see...

Comment: My best guess at a translation: He wants to replace "is" with "was" in the string "This is my name."

Comment: Yeah, and how about the last sentence : *Justify proof by dig* :-)

Answer (score 3):

Something similar to this should do what you asked in many languages:

```
s = s.replace('is', 'was');
```

However on your example string this will give:

```
Thwas was my name
```

Note that `This` has been changed to `Thwas` because it contains the string `is`. If you want to match only words rather than substrings you might want to use a regular expression instead and use word boundaries. In some languages you can use the following regular expression:

```
/\bis\b/
```

The syntax will vary slightly depending on the language.

Comment: `+1` Way to answer something that isn't a question!

Comment: you didn't *justify your proof by dig* :-)

Comment: @Darin as you don't know what it means Mark could well have justified his proof by dig, repeatedly, by accident!